# Don't try this if you don't know your maths!

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Find the next number in this sequence:

> $120, 106, 112, 108, 80, 92, 84,...$

This sequence might be easy for some, but you won't be able to solve it if you don't know a certain subject in maths (That I will reveal if nobody finds the answer in 30 minutes).

First Hint:

> Look at the title!

Second Hint:

> It doesn't involve any special series or integrals.

Third hint:

> It is in the number theory puzzle

Fourth hint:

> It is an easy recurrence relation.

Fifth hint:

> It uses a well known function

Sixth hint:

> 120 and 106 are just starting values

Comment: 550? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @warspyking No sorry that's not the answer. How did you arrive a that answer?

Comment: I used an addition table

Comment: -594? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @warspyking no the number is a positive integer. There's addition but there's something else involved

Comment: If this can help someone : notice each number is even

Comment: @The random guy Nice observation. Could you find anything interesting by looking at the hints? Some numbers in this sequence can be repeated.

Comment: I feel like 120 is there to throw me off...

Comment: @Martijn R Well you just reminded me of another hint

Comment: Does it make use of summation, product or limits?

Comment: @MartijnR, my hypothesis is that it's a Fibonacci-like sequence which is then pointwise mapped through another number-theoretic function, perhaps Euler's phi.

Comment: what about "It uses a well known function"?? as per answer it is not "well known" function.

Comment: @Saurabh Prajapati maybe you don't know it yet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The next number in this sequence is,

> $80$

Because the sequence is defined as such:

> $a_0 = 120,\:a_1 = 106,\:a_n = \phi(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2})$
>
>  Where $\phi$ denotes [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function), defined as the number of integers between 1 and $x-1$ inclusive that are coprime to $x$.

The sequence continues,

> $120,\,106,\,112,\,108,\,80,\,92,\,84,\,80,\,80,\,64,\,48,\,48,\,\overline{32,\,32,\,32},\,\dots$

Comment: I looked at this Wikipedia page... Good job on figuring this out!

Comment: I don't know why I tried sigma, but not phi. (If you could see deleted answers, you could see that I even posted one (wrong) answer)

Comment: Bravo that's the right answer pal

Answer (score 6):

The sequence and its difference sequence are-

> $S = 120,\ 106,\ 112,\ 108,\ 80,\ 92,\ 84,...$
>   $\Delta S= -14,\ 6,\ -4,\ -28,\ 12,\ -8...$

It seems that the difference sequence doubles every 3 terms. So, I would guess that the next three terms in the difference sequence would be

> -14, 6, -4, -28, 12, -8, **(-56, 24, -16)** or **(-42,18,-12)**

So, the next terms might be:

> 120, 106, 112, 108, 80, 92, 84, **(28, 52, 36)** or **(42, 60, 48)**

Comment: It's a bit more complicated. Look at the hint, it says you'll have to use NUMBER THEORY. Maybe you'll find a pattern by exploiting that. But differences here won't get you to the answer.

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Simple is better than complicated, otherwise we can just use polynomial fittings for any sequence question.

Comment: It's not very compmicated. No polynomials or series are involved here. Well I think this time for a new hint

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Okay, waiting to see the intended solution. I do hope that it is better than mine. I myself would have been disappointed at the question if this was the answer.

Comment: Well look at the new hint and see what you can do.

Answer (score 4):

These are the known numbers so far:

$$
S = \left(\begin{matrix}
 0 & 120 \\
 1 & 106 \\
 2 & 112 \\
 3 & 108 \\
 4 & 80 \\
 5 & 92 \\
 6 & 84
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

When investigating the numbers, I noticed a pattern in them:

$$
\Delta S = 112 - 106 = 6 \\
\Delta S = 112 - 108 = 4
$$

$$
\Delta S = 92 - 80 = 12 \\
\Delta S = 92 - 84 = 8
$$

These number seem to be related to each other in groups of 3 and their $\Delta$'s between each other seem to be doubling. Backwards engineering using this, leaves us with:

$$
\Delta S = a - 120 = 2 \\
a = 2 \\
S(-1) = 122
$$

Now let's compare the highest numbers of all the known triplets:

$$
\Delta S = 122 - 112 = 10 \\
\Delta S = 112 - 92 = 20
$$

Which confirms my theory that the pattern must be:

$$
\text{in }\mathbb{Z} \\[12pt]
S(x) = \begin{cases}
S(x+1) - \left(6 * 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}{3}\right\rfloor}\right) & \text{if } ((x-1) \text{ mod } 3) = 0 \\
132 - \left(20 * 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}{3}\right\rfloor}\right) & \text{if } ((x-2) \text{ mod } 3) = 0 \\
S(x-1) - \left(4 * 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}{3}\right\rfloor}\right) & \text{if } (x \text{ mod } 3) = 0
\end{cases}
$$

The next number in the sequence would be:

$$
\begin{align}
S(7) &= S(7+1) - \left(6 * 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{7-1}{3}\right\rfloor}\right) \\
&= \left(132 - \left(20 * 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{8-1}{3}\right\rfloor}\right)\right) - \left(6 * 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{7-1}{3}\right\rfloor}\right) \\
&= \left(132 - \left(20 * 4\right)\right) - \left(6 * 4\right) \\
&= \left(132 - 80\right) - 24 \\
&= 52 - 24 \\
&= 28
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Ah no that's not the right answer but +1. Just one thing, why nobody used the fact that there's a number theoretical function involved and the relationship is very simple.

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Hmm, you made this hard for me. I really don't see the function...

Comment: If you find the function then you have your solution. At first I tought you found the answer as $S(-1)$ and $S(0)$ followed the sequence

Comment: @OussamaBoussif There was an error in my maths. I corrected it.

Comment: You got farther from the solution than you were before.